# Failed to read Firefox OS indexeddb for backup completely

Tags: sqlite, backup, indexeddb, firefox-os

Finally I need to change my current smartphone with firefox OS on it, due to some problems with the speaker.
Anyway I would like to backup not only the contacts, but also the messages (sms).
I found this great tutorial and the work of laenion http://digitalimagecorp.de/flatpress/?x=cat:8? and was able to retrieve the sqlite database of the messages.

Anyway laenion Exporter http://digitalimagecorp.de/software/firefox-os-data-exporter/ffosexporter.html? is only exporting the last messages from each thread, but I want to have a full backup.

Now I started reading in the file with his recommendation of the Firefox Storage Manager. Now it happens, that I can read out 2351 entries and then the conversion stops. However, if I delete some rows and do a restart it loads additional entries up to 2351 again.

Now I am wondering, is there a value in the `about:config` on how to extend the keys to be converted? Or is there anything else I am doing wrong? Why is the storage manager not reading in the complete database?

Thanks for any hint on how to solve it. Unfortunately I was not able to open the database in a readable style with any other program.